# Starting Activity in listview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

private String mstring[] = { "MainActivity", "Activity2", "Activity3",
        "Activity4" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mstring));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String positn = mstring[position];

    try {
        Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.list" + positn);
        Intent inten = new Intent(Menu.this, ourclass);
        startActivity(inten);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

I want to start activity from listview but this is not working, how it will b possible to start activity on list item click.

here is logcat:

```
04-12 13:32:27.728: W/System.err(15518): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.apaooo.MainActivity
04-12 13:32:27.728: W/System.err(15518):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-12 13:32:27.728: W/System.err(15518):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
04-12 13:32:27.728: W/System.err(15518):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
04-12 13:32:27.728: W/System.err(15518):    at com.example.appaooo.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:29)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1104)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2792)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3468)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 13:32:27.738: W/System.err(15518): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/apaooo/MainActivity
04-12 13:32:27.748: W/System.err(15518):    ... 18 more
04-12 13:32:27.748: W/System.err(15518): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.apaooo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.appaooo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.appaooo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-12 13:32:27.748: W/System.err(15518):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
04-12 13:32:27.748: W/System.err(15518):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-12 13:32:27.748: W/System.err(15518):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-12 13:32:27.748: W/System.err(15518):    ... 18 more
```

MianActivity.java

```
package com.example.appaooo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Context context = this;
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGeo);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Manifest file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.appaooo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:theme="@style/customTheme"
        android:name="com.example.appaooo.Menu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.appaooo.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>

</application>
```

first i am trying to start main activity only

Comment: please check your activity name

Comment: activity name is ture

Comment: @user3468384 either the package name is different in manifest or the package name in MainActivity does not match the one in manifest. So check those and fix it. It will work. You still haven't posted manifest and Activity code with imports

Comment: @user3468384 it should work if you followed my post.

Comment: which post i should follow3.

Comment: @user3468384 whatever i have suggested in my answer will work. Looking at the code and the manifest it looks alright to me. Other than that i have nothing to suggest. Good luck. Just clean and build once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.list" + positn);// .missing
```

to

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.list."+positn);
```

Make sure you have declared all activities in manifest file

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.apaooo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.appaooo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.appaooo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Your package name is probably

```
com.example.apaooo
```

So it should be

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.apaooo."+positn);
```

Comment: That's eagle eye catch :)

Comment: activities has declared in manifest but still the same problem

Comment: @user3468384 post the stacktrace which will indicate the cause

Comment: @user3468384 check the edited answer. make sure the packagename form manifest and the activity matches

Comment: @user3468384 not its not read the stacktrace classnotfoundexception.

Comment: @user3468384 by posting manifest file and the MainActivity.java full we will be able to see if its the right package

Answer (score 0):

replace your this line code

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.list" + positn);
```

with this line

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.apaooo." + positn);
```

and make sure each activity is registered in Manifest.xml with this package name.
[image]